# Excel VBA Saving Sheet to Path as Excel File and Overwriting File

Tags: excel, vba, save

I'm having some trouble getting something pretty basic to work.  Any ideas what's wrong here?

```
Sub Test()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master List").SaveAs "C:\Test\ART.xlsx", 52

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `Copy` the worksheet first and then save the `ActiveWorkbook`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Export Worksheet

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub exportSheet()
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Test\"
    Const FileName As String = "ART.xlsx"
    Const SheetName As String = "Master List"
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks(FileName).Close
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        .Sheets(SheetName).Copy
        With ActiveWorkbook
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .SaveAs FolderPath & FileName, xlOpenXMLWorkbook ' 51 (.xlsx)
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            .Close False
        End With
        ' Open Folder Path in Windows File Explorer.
        '.FollowHyperlink FolderPath
        '.Close
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: VBasic, 2 quick questions for you.  I was running this and it works, but there's 2 pitfalls for the specific scenario I'm solving for..  1 - Is it possible to paste values instead of pasting formulas?  2 - Is there a logical way to control permissions where saving and overwriting the file can be run by multiple users?  I noticed if I run the process and save the file, and then someone else runs it, it will error out and say priviledges aren't there.  Great solution, either way, appreciate the help!

Comment: If the values copied are ok, then you could e.g. do `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value` after `.Sheets(SheetName).Copy`. if not, you'll have to use another way to copy. Sorry, but I don't know anything about permissions, yet.